# Grouping verbs for simultaneously or received actions

Tags: grammar

Using 動詞＋たり＋動詞＋たり　＋　するwe can describe a group actions.

Hows is this done when its a recieved action: ie て刑　＋もらう・いだだく?

ie, Would:
 **Aをしてくれたり、Bをしてくれたり　　からありがたいです**

or

**Aをしたり、Bをしたり　してもらったからありがたいです。**

or something else be the best way to express that?

Similarly, I understand that a pair of actions done simultaneously can be expressed using しながら, but can you, and if so how can you scale it to include more than 2 verbs?

ie could you just say AをしながらBをしながらCをしまし? It seems verbose and unnatural but i dont know how to express doing say 3 things at once for example.

Answer (score 3):

You can use both forms.

> - 声をかけてくれたり手伝ってくれたりしたので、Aさんには感謝しています。
> - 声をかけたり手伝ったりしてくれたので、Aさんには感謝しています。

Or if the two verbs are suru-verbs, you can say:

> - Aさんが応援してくれたり助言してくれたりしたことをありがたく思います。
> - Aさんが応援したり助言したりしてくれたことをありがたく思います。

But these are obviously wordy and complicated. "Aさんに応援や助言をいただき、ありがたく思います" or something similar would be better.

(I chose other expressions for "I appreciate ～", because ～からありがたいです is uncommon in the first place. This is not related to your main problem.)